# What is the origin of the antihero Deadpool's character name?

Tags: origins, deadpool

What's the story behind Deadpool's name? Most comicbook characters have names that reflect their powers, or even their costumes, but I can't make an association with either his outfit or his healing ability.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the [Deadpool and Death Annual 1999](https://www.comixology.com/Deadpool-Death-Annual/digital-comic/29469) we learn the origin of Deadpool's name; simply put, when he was being experimented on (as part of the programme which ultimately led to his powers) the guards and inmates had a [dead pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_pool) where they would gamble on which subject would die next. He took his name from this.

[image]

[image]

---

Out of universe, [ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/deadpool/4005-7606/) indicates that the name (and concept) were chosen as an homage to the [5th Dirty Harry movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094963/). Although they're usually very accurate about these things, I can't find any quotes to back this up.

Comment: The other Out-of-Universe explanation of the name I've heard has to do with him being a ripoff of Deathstroke especially in his first appearance. "Where do you do the Deathstroke? In the Deadpool."

Comment: @seanduggan - good luck finding someone from DC who'll admit that...

Comment: @Richard especially since he's a Marvel character.

Comment: @phantom42 - Well, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

From an out-of-continuity perspective, co-creator Rob Liefeld had a habit of using action movie titles/ and or pop culture references for character names. Hence, Deadpool, Diehard, Shaft, Bedrock, etc.

Comment: Hi. You've posted several answers already, and while we welcome your participation and enthusiasm, you need to read the [site guidelines](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/answering) for writing good questions and answers. There have been problems with each of your answers so far, and you should address those issues before moving on to new answers. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I've been up all night. I'll take a more detailed run through the guidelines after I get some sleep.